# How do I sort column-wise a pandas dataframe based on the column-wise sort of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have two pandas data frames, and I am trying to sort them column-wise in relation to each other.

One represents similar words and the other represents a similarity score. I want to sort the similarity score dataframe column wise (sort_values, axis=1), *and* apply the same sorting to the original dataframe of the words. They have the exact same index and number of columns.

Dataframe #1 (the words):

| index | Col 0 | Col 1 | Col 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Trains | Rockets | Cars | Ships |
| Paintings | Canvases | Paint | Ink |
| Germs | Infections | Dirt | Dust |

Dataframe #2 (similarity score):

| index | Col 0 | Col 1 | Col 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Trains | 47 | 80 | 33 |
| Paintings | 22 | 90 | 30 |
| Germs | 77 | 40 | 52 |

Desired dataframe (the words sorted, based on the sorted values of dataframe #2):

| index | Col 0 | Col 1 | Col 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Trains | Cars | Rockets | Ships |
| Paintings | Paint | Canvases | Ink |
| Germs | Infections | Dust | Dirt |

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a job for np.argsort

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to get `df2`'s sorted order and use it to reorder `df1` with numpy indexing:

```
import numpy as np

df1[:] = df1.to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df1))[:, None], np.argsort(-df2)]
```

*NB. sorting `-df2` to get the descending order.*

Output:

```
                Col 0    Col 1     Col 2
Trains           Cars  Rockets     Ships
Paintings       Paint      Ink  Canvases
Germs      Infections     Dust      Dirt
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Col 0': {'Trains': 'Rockets', 'Paintings': 'Canvases', 'Germs': 'Infections'}, 
         'Col 1': {'Trains': 'Cars', 'Paintings': 'Paint', 'Germs': 'Dirt'}, 
         'Col 2': {'Trains': 'Ships', 'Paintings': 'Ink', 'Germs': 'Dust'}}
data2 = {'Col 0': {'Trains': 47, 'Paintings': 22, 'Germs': 77}, 
         'Col 1': {'Trains': 80, 'Paintings': 90, 'Germs': 40}, 
         'Col 2': {'Trains': 33, 'Paintings': 30, 'Germs': 52}}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

df1:

[image]

---

**Code**

unpivot(here `stack`) & merge(here `concat`) & sort & pivot (here `set_index` + `unstack`)

```
out = pd.concat([df1.stack(), df2.stack()], axis=1)\
        .droplevel(1).sort_values(1, ascending=False)\
        .assign(cols=lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount().astype('str').radd('Col '))\
        .set_index('cols', append=True)[0].unstack().reindex_like(df1)
```

out

```
                Col 0    Col 1     Col 2                                   
Trains           Cars  Rockets     Ships
Paintings       Paint      Ink  Canvases
Germs      Infections     Dust      Dirt
```